# How to debug ReactJS's setState

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently working on a medium sized reactJS application and get the following error message after I click a button on a component:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
```

How can I debug this more easily? Why doesn't reactJS give me a specific component name where this rule was violated?

How would you do it?

Comment: I'd just look for anything using Ajax or timers ... Possibly within `componentDidMount` as the inner callback could be executed **after** the component had already become unmounted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the best way to solve this issue is by changing some react code locally.

[This pull-request](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/3913) specifically points out how to modify `src/renderers/shared/reconciler/ReactUpdateQueue.js` to get the component that illegaly sets state.

As this pull-request was already merged into the repo, it shouldn't be to long before it will be integrated into an npm version of react, one could hope.

Answer (score 13):

You can override `console.warn` to make it throw instead of log when the provided message matches a certain pattern. In your case, you'd do:

```js
var warn = console.warn;
console.warn = function(warning) {
  if (/(setState)/.test(warning)) {
    throw new Error(warning);
  }
  warn.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

The stack trace of the error will then point to the line causing the warnings.

Comment: This is actually quite clever but for some reason doesn't work for me

Comment: Ah ok, I figured why - the message getting logged said 'WARNING: ...' but it was actually an error log. So I had to replace 'warn' from your snippet with 'error'.
I wish I could buy you coffee :)